# Excel X - Axis appearing differently in charts

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have an Excel graph that takes the values of X-axis as January 2015, February 2015, etc., But Unfortunately, it shows up in the form of numbers as 0,1,2,3,4 etc.,

I tried the solutions of changing the data for it through Select Data option. It got updated in the Select Data box as January 2015, February 2015 but not reflecting the same in the chart.

[image: This is the select Data Image and you could see , its reflected on the data but not on the graph]

Comment: Try formatting the x-axis (right-click on the axis) and make sure the "number" property is set to type "date".

Comment: @Bandersnatch No, sorry to confuse you here. The problem was with the chart type and not the data format.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that the problem was with the chart type. I have used a Scatter Plot which doesn't accepts categories on the x-axis and now after changing it to a line chart, it started working for me. Thanks everyone